# How to increase the X and Y coordinations

Tags: android, view

I am using setX and setY in order to move a view programmaticly. I want to increase the X coordination and do something like this:
v.setX(newX+ 10)
but it doesn't work.
here is my XML - I want to update ths coorsinations of the image view "imgBall0"

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/GoolotPlayer1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/HolesPlayer1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGoolot0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="  0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGoolot1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="  0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGoolot2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="  0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGoolot3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="  0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGoolot4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="  0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGoolot5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:text="  0" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBall4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/GoolotPlayer1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/GoolotPlayer1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="108dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/goola2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBall1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/goola0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBall0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgBall1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgBall3"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/goola0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBall2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imgBall4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/GoolotPlayer1"
    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/goola2" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/HolesPlayer1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvGoolot6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/hole0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/hole0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/hole0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/hole0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/hole0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/hole0" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgBtn13"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/HolesPlayer2"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/home0" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/HolesPlayer2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgBtn13"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgBtn6" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/hole0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/hole0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/hole0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/hole0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/hole0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn12"
        style="@drawable/hole01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/hole0" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvGoolot6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgBtn6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgBtn6"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:text="  0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvGoolot13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/HolesPlayer1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgBtn13"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text=" 0" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/GoolotPlayer2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imgBtn13"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgBtn13" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGoolot12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="  0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGoolot11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="  0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGoolot10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="  0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGoolot9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="  0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGoolot8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="  0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGoolot7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:text="  0" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBall3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgBall1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/GoolotPlayer1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/goola2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgBtn6"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/GoolotPlayer2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/HolesPlayer1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/home0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvWhoseTurn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/GoolotPlayer2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgBall1"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Here is the method i tried- when clicking an imageButton it should update the coordinations of "imgBall0" to the place of the view that was clicked (it suppose to be **on** it)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{

    int[] location = new int[2];

    v.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    float startX = location[0];
    float startY = location[1];
    tvWhoseTurn.setText(startX+" "+startY);
    littleBalls[0].setX(startX);
    littleBalls[0].setY(startY- HolesPlayer2.getHeight()+10); //"+10" doesn't work
    littleBalls[0].bringToFront();  

}
```

Is there a way to do it??
thanks in advance, I will be glad for a quick answer

Comment: You'll need to give some more info. Could you post the code where you're trying to do this.

Comment: your view is in some layout, your layout is not allowing your setX setY to work. Post code for more info, xml also.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTranslateY()` that's api 11+ or you could use the `Animation` api or you could use `LayoutParam`s. have you heard of Top, Left,Right,Bottom ? yes you can change them respectively and have them move. The things you would need for that is a `Thread` an `atomic int variable`, a `while loop` that is going to run till you reach your positon and a lil maths.

*if you had posted codes i would have looked on it and write you codes- but we all resolve to words right??*

something like this

```
boolean right = true;
private Runnable trans = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(right){
            layout(getLeft()+translate, getTop(), getRight()+translate, getBottom());
        }else {
            layout(getLeft()-translate, getTop(), getRight()-translate, getBottom());
        }
        invalidate();// this line is needed
    }
};
```

then

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
          while(true) //need to use a boolean so you can stop it later
          /* add a thread.sleep() to pause your loop for some millie seconds*/
          handler.post(trans);// handler is a Handler object
```

it will animate..

hope it helps..*sorry for the lazy code in a hurray*

Comment: Sorry friend, I thought it doesn't neccesery in that case, I just add them now.. Thanks for your time :)